# MYSQL Trigger - storing updated table data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that tracks the number of hours an employee took on a job.

```
    CREATE TABLE HOURLYWORKLOG (
EMPLOYEEREF               INT(5) NOT NULL,
ORDERREF                  INT(5) NOT NULL,
HOURSWORKED               VARCHAR(10),
TOTALPAY                  NUMERIC(10),
NOTES                     VARCHAR(10),
CONSTRAINT HOURLYWORKLOG_EMPLOYEES_FOREIGN_KEY FOREIGN KEY (EMPLOYEEREF) REFERENCES EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEEREF),
CONSTRAINT HOURLYWORKLOG_ORDERS_FOREIGN_KEY FOREIGN KEY (ORDERREF) REFERENCES WORKORDER (ORDERREF));
```

I am looking to create a trigger that stores this data in a separate table if the hoursworked column is updated. Reading around, I can't see anything that explains what I need to do, at least I can't understand the steps involved after reading. As such my current solution is through creating a mirrored table (with a different name)

```
CREATE TABLE MODIFIEDHOURLYWORKLOG (
EMPLOYEEREF               INT(5) NOT NULL,
ORDERREF                  INT(5) NOT NULL,
HOURSWORKED               VARCHAR(10),
TOTALPAY                  NUMERIC(10),
NOTES                     VARCHAR(10));
```

And then creating a trigger as such

```
CREATE TRIGGER MODIFIEDHWL ON HOURLYWORKLOG
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO MODIFIEDHOURLYWORKLOG
(EMPLOYEEREF, ORDERREF, HOURSWORKED, TOTALPAY, NOTES)
SELECT I.EMPLOYEEREF, I.ORDERREF, I.HOURSWORKED, I.TOTALPAY, I.NOTES
FROM HOURLYWORKLOG T
INNER JOIN INSERTED I ON T.EMPLOYEEREF-I.EMPLOYEEREF
END;
```

This obviously isn't working and is throwing up errors that my syntax is incorrect. I'm not sure how to write a trigger to transfer the data from the original table into the secondary one basically...

Thank you for any help.

Comment: `INNER JOIN INSERTED I ON T.EMPLOYEEREF-I.EMPLOYEEREF` Typo? rather use `ON T.EMPLOYEEREF=I.EMPLOYEEREF`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by each row, but each time a value is altered in the hoursworked column I need a record saved?

Comment: your question says if the hoursworked column is updated  and you created an insert trigger which one do you want i guess on update

Comment: The hoursworked column I believe.

Comment: Every statement must be terminated and you should be setting delimiters https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html. And you need to clarify whether you want an insert or update trigger. Sample data and desired outcome would also help.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use trigger syntax for MySQL, not SQL Server.  Something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER MODIFIEDHWL ON HOURLYWORKLOG AFTER INSERT
    FOR EACH ROW AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MODIFIEDHOURLYWORKLOG(EMPLOYEEREF, ORDERREF, HOURSWORKED, TOTALPAY, NOTES)
        SELECT NEW.EMPLOYEEREF, NEW.ORDERREF, NEW.HOURSWORKED, NEW.TOTALPAY, NEW.NOTES
        FROM DUAL
        WHERE NOT NEW.HOURSWORKED <=> OLD.HOURSWORKED;
END;$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER MODIFIEDHWL ON HOURLYWORKLOG
after update
for each row
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO MODIFIEDHOURLYWORKLOG
(EMPLOYEEREF, ORDERREF, HOURSWORKED, TOTALPAY, NOTES)
SELECT NEW.EMPLOYEEREF, NEW.ORDERREF, NEW.HOURSWORKED, NEW.TOTALPAY, 
NEW.NOTES
from dual where NEW.HOURSWORKED != OLD.HOURSWORKED
END;
/
```